# discord py while loop breaks with no reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I made a discord bot which is supposed to send a quote from a text file every day at 22:00 UTC time. While it does work once, it seems the while-loop breaks after the first day.

```py
import discord
import random
import datetime

client = discord.Client()
text_channel = None

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    global text channel

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    cntnt = message.content

    if cntnt == '!add_channel':
        text_channel = message.channel
        print("Assigned ", text_channel, " as channel.")        
        await message.delete()

    if cntnt == '!start_quote':
        if text_channel != None:
            await message.delete()
            while True:
                current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                print(current_time)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                time1 = current_time.hour
                time2 = current_time.minute
                if time1 == 22 and time2 == 0:
                    with open('quotes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
                        quotes = file.readlines()
                    index = random.randint(0, len(quotes))
                    answer = str(quotes[index + 1])
                    await text_channel.send("Today's quote: " + answer)
                    await asyncio.sleep(60)
        else:
            print("No channel assigned.")
            await message.delete()


client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Fix your code's indentation. As is gives a syntax error.

Comment: I doubt the bot should be inside the on_message() for so long.

Comment: I think it is like this, because everything refers to `message.content` or general the `message`. But it seems like some parts of the code are missing, for example `cntnt` is never declared. @ThomasWeller

Comment: Thats a mistake I did while copy-pasting I fixed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the while loop isn't actually breaking, but your bot is being overloaded. You're putting this while loop, which runs indefinitely, inside an on_message handler. That means that a new loop starts every time someone sends a message.

A much better way to achieve this is with [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). Here is an example:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def send_quote():
   # send the quote here, no while loop needed

send_quote.start()  # don't forget, you always have to call the start() method
```

[EDIT]
If you need to send the message at a certain time every day, then you could do something like this:

```py
import datetime

last_send = None
send_at = datetime.time(hours=12)  # send at the twelf hour every day

# wait at least 2 hours before allowing a second quote.
# this prevents sending twice at the same time.
min_difference = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def send_quote():
   # First, check if the time is right.
   now = datetime.datetime.now()

   # check that it's been at least 10 minutes since the last send
   # to prevent sending twice at the same time.
   if last_send is None or (now - last_send < min_difference):
       # this will check if the hour is correct
       if send_at.hour - now.hour == 0:
           # send the quote here
           last_send = now  # update last_send
```

I wasn't able to test this, so I can't guarantee that it will work right away.

Comment: I tried this but this way I would have to start the bot at exactly 22:00 UTC time which would be 3am for me, right? Since it just does the task every 24hours and not at a certain time. Or could I make @tasks.loop(minutes=1) to check every 1 mins if its 22:00?

Comment: Thanks this worked, but I think it's `send_at.hour - now.hour == 0`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would reccoment is not using the `if cntnt`, but rather moving to the discord.ext package.

Example:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello")
```